# Dominating function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $$f_n: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ be a sequence of integrable functions converging uniformally towards $f$. Prove that for a finite measure, $\mu$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f_n d\mu = \int f d\mu $$

My teacher put online a proof of this implication using the dominated convergence theorem with the function

$g(x) = |f_1|+|f_2|+...+|f_n|+2$ where $\forall m \geq n$ we have $|f_m-f|\leq 1$. I understand why such a $g$ exists and why it's integrable, but I have trouble seeing why it would be greater than any $f_m$. (Obviously if $m\leq n$ it's trivial.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that you are all right with the case $m\leq n$, I will just focus on the case $m>n$.

Let us set $g'(x):=|f_n(x)|+2$ with the hypothesis that $\forall m\geq n(|f-f_m|<1$ (so $g'<g$). Let $m>n$ be fixed. Let us evaluate $A:=g'(x)-f_m(x)=g'(x)-f(x)+f(x)-f_m(x).$

By hypothesis $f(x)-f_m(x)\geq-1$. Similarly, $f(x)_n-f(x)\geq-1$, which implies $g'(x)-f(x)\geq -1+2=1$. Hence, $A\geq 0$, which means that $g$ dominates $f_m$.

Comment: Thank you! Shouldn't it be  $$g'(x)−f_m(x)≥−1-1+2=0$$, though? Which would work too!

Comment: Yes, it is basically what I meant (I recognize now I may have written my answer in a more convoluted way than necessary), I simply added the "$+2$" beforehand, thus obtaining $A=\dots\geq+1-1$